# Conjugacy of cocharacters from conjugacy of labelled diagrams

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, characteristic-p

Everything to follow is over some fixed algebraically closed field $k$.  Although all the definitions make sense regardless of characteristic, the meat of the question is about small positive characteristic.

If $G$ is a reductive group, then a cocharacter $\lambda$ of $G$ attaches an integer to every element of the root system of $G$: after choosing a maximal torus $T$ containing the image of $\lambda$, we have for each root $\alpha$ of $T$ in $G$ an action of $\operatorname{GL}_1$ on the $\alpha$-weight space $\operatorname{Lie}(G)_\alpha$, which necessarily sends $t$ to multiplication by $t^{n_\alpha}$ for some integer $n_\alpha$.

If we forget all the integers but those attached to the roots in some fixed simple system, then we obtain a labelling of the Dynkin diagram by integers.  Different choices of maximal torus $T$ and of simple root system need not produce the same labelled diagram, but the labels will differ only by a diagram automorphism.

Lemma 2.2.8 of [Liebeck and Seitz - The maximal subgroups of positive dimension in exceptional algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0802) states that two cocharacters determine the same labelling of the Dynkin diagram, up to diagram automorphism, if and only if they are conjugate in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)(k)$, if and only if the weights for the resulting actions of $\operatorname{GL}_1$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ on the same.  This is claimed to follow from the proof of [23, 6.3], where [23] is [Liebeck and Seitz - Reductive subgroups of exceptional algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0580).

Theorem 6.3 of [23] claims that, if one uses a homomorphism to $G$ from $\operatorname{SL}_2$ rather than just from $\operatorname{GL}_1$, and if the two actions of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ have the same composition factors, then the resulting labelled diagrams are the same (up to diagram automorphism).  I am perfectly willing to take Liebeck and Seitz's word for it that this proof (which extends over 5 pages in a simplified version) actually only uses the action of the diagonal torus in $\operatorname{SL}_2$.

However, this seems to prove only one of the claimed equivalences, and the equivalence that interests me is the one that deduces $\operatorname{Aut}(G)(k)$-conjugacy from equality of the labelled diagrams.  This does not seem to be covered by Theorem 6.3 of [23] at all.  It *is* covered by Theorem 6.4.  Again, this result actually uses the action of a whole $\operatorname{SL}_2$, but I am willing to believe that in some way the proof boils down just to the action of the diagonal torus.  However, the proof, which extends over 15 pages, involves careful case-by-case checking and, crucially, restrictions on the characteristic of $k$, with some cases involving very small primes not handled at all.  In the setting of [Liebeck and Seitz - The maximal subgroups of positive dimension in exceptional algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0802), and for the use to which I wish to put it, it is important that no characteristic restriction is imposed.  So how does the proof of Lemma 2.2.8 follow?